# Using MySQL or r, or both?

Tags: mysql, r

I have a large dataset and I want to do statistical analysis on certain subsets of the data.

At the moment I see this as a two step procedure:

1. Import data into a MySQL database and use the world of SELECT, JOIN, WHERE etc
2. Export the resulting data to be then imported into r, and then do the statistics in r.

My question(s) is (are): Is this an efficient workflow? Could one do this completely in r? Can one simulate MySQL select syntax in r?

Comment: (1) If the data-set is too large for memory (or if you want it in a database for other reasons) then you can smooth the workflow by sending SQL commands from R using e.g. `RMySQL` to retrieve subsets as data frames. (2) Otherwise you can read the data into R & perform the data manipulation within R using either (a) SQL syntax see `sqldf`,  or (b) native R commands for subsetting, joining &c., or (c) other R packages like `plyr` or `reshape2`

Comment: @Nick I read this question a little differently.  I cannot find where it is asking to compare software.  It appears to ask about how to process a "large" dataset efficiently in `R`.  Presumably "large" means too large for `R` to handle directly in RAM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context of a single computer it would be more efficient to do this completely in R. Once your data size gets past the RAM of your computer, but you have access to a MySQL server somewhere with more resources then it might be easier to use the two-step procedure you described. Given, of course, that the dataset you want to do stats with will fit into memory after data selection and aggregation is done in SQL.

There is several tools that simulate SQL in R:

- SQLDF is the most straighforward as you can use SQL on your data frame.
- data.table implements more efficient version of a data frame and has it's own syntax that maps to SQL, so you can do selects, joins, etc.
- [dplyr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/dplyr.pdf) is a kind of a user-friendly version of data.table package.

There's a pretty good / overview on how to use dplyr - http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html

Comment: (+1) Note dplyr can also send SQL to external databases. No need for the export part of the two-step procedure.